# Ubuntu 14 creating file under /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Tags: bash, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, createfile

I am trying to install postgree on Ubuntu 14 as explained here:
http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

And trying to create file inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory:

```
sudo echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

but get this error:

> bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list: Permission denied

How I should do that?

Comment: If bash is telling you `Permission denied` you probably do not have root permissions. You should add your user to the suddoers file.

Comment: Seems not this case: The user `dav' is already a member of `sudo'.

Comment: Check @Tym answer in askubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer to [this answered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103643/cannot-echo-hello-x-txt-even-with-sudo) : "The redirection is done by the shell before sudo is even started. "